# disable default authentication in mongo docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to disable the default auth
(avoid to use mongo --authenticationDatabase "auth_db").

in mongo using docker-compose, here is my **docker-compose** file:

```
version: "2"

services:
    mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment: 
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=some_user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just don't pass the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`
env vars when creating the container.

Comment: Yes, not passing the below env params works! Thanks @pacuna!